# Mockito anyListOf Pair class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Class A--Has a method 'doSomething' which accepts a list of Pair

Class B--Has a method which internally calls Class A's method.

I am trying to write Junit for Class B , where I need to verify Mocked Class A's mentod is called with Pair type.

```
verify(a,times(1)).doSomething(Mockito.anyListOf(Pair.class))
```

I need a way to specify something like

```
verify(a,times(1)).doSomething(Mockito.anyListOf(Pair<CustomClass1,CustomClass2>.class))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer to the question but an alternative (Probably a better option).
I ended up using Argument Captor to capture the argument and then I can assert the captured values to verify they match against expected values.

```
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<List<Pair<CustomClass1, CustomClass2>>> pairListArgCaptor;

//Capture Values
verify(a,times(1)).doSomething(pairListArgCaptor.capture());

assertEquals(expectedCustomObject1,pairListArgCaptor.get().get(0).getFirst());
assertEquals(expectedCustomObject2,pairListArgCaptor.get().get(0).getSecond());
```

Answer (score 0):

Java won't let a class have two methods with the same erasure; so provided `doSomething(List)` is invoked, it will be with a `List<Pair<CustomClass1,CustomClass2>>`.

As such, you should simply be able to use:

```
verify(a,times(1)).doSomething(Mockito.anyList());
```

or, if there are no other single-argument overloads of `doSomething`:

```
verify(a,times(1)).doSomething(Mockito.any());
```

Comment: Thanks.
Yes Mockito.any() would work fine.I am trying to make my verify statement as concrete as possible

Comment: And what if you have a method like this `public <T extends A> void dosom(List<T> lst)`? I would like verify if the method is invoked with the correct extension of A ...

Comment: @Renato then you wouldn't be using `any`. But, there's no such thing as a "list with a specific extension of `A`": it's just a `List`. All you can ever test about the generic type of the list is a lower bound on the elements, and even then only if it is non-empty.

Comment: @AndyTurner this is exactly what i thought while reading your answer: `any` doesn't apply in all cases, also if is true that java doesn't accept overloading with the same erasure

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to use

```
verify(a, times(1)).doSomething(Mockito.argThat(<HERE_COMES_ARGUMENT_MATCHER_INSTANCE>)); // see below
```

An `ArgumentMatcher` is an abstraction that mockito uses in order to implement custom verification logic:

```
private class MyMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<List<Pair>> {
    private final List<Pair> expected; 

    public PointMatcher(List<Pair> expected) {
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof List<Pair>)) {
            return false;
        }
        List<Pair>actual = (List<Pair>) obj;

        return // implement your custom logic here and return boolean if it matches
    }
}
```

In this particular example I use a matcher that can compare the actual list with something that it expects, however you can create a matcher that will do have a "weaker" criterion of comparison.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Bramnik. I've user Argument Captor instead.I think there is a very thin line which separates Argument Matcher and Argument Captor. I feel Argument Captor is more suited for this scenario. I referred the below blog.

https://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/11/25/mockito-argumentmatcher-vs-argumentcaptor/